# how to install py-fhe library from the github repo?

Tags: python, encryption, installation, anaconda

Can anybody give me some clear instructions about how to install this library from Anaconda Powershell Prompt on windows 10 for my Jupyter notebook env from here?

https://github.com/sarojaerabelli/py-fhe

e.g. do I need to run the setup.py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open a Jupyter notebook running in the env you want to work in and save it with a distinguishable name.
2. Go to https://github.com/sarojaerabelli/py-fhe and click on the green '`<>Code`' button and choose to Download ZIP file to your system.
3. Move the Zip file to where you saved your Jupyter Notebook.
4. Use your system's way to unpack ZIP files to unpack the ZIP file there. Maybe you can simply double-click it since you have Windows that probably can handle unpacking a `.zip` file. (What I did was in my notebook run `!unzip master`, but that was running on a remote linux machine.)
5. That should produce a directory named `py-fhe-master/`. In your Jupyter Notebook, run the command `%cd py-fhe-master/` to change the working directory in the notebook to that directory.
6. Next, run in your notebook [the command provided in the documentation on how to install it](https://github.com/sarojaerabelli/py-fhe#installation):   `%pip install -e .`, being careful to get the whole command because the period is part of it.
7. Restart the kernel, and it should be installed now. [As described in the documentation](https://github.com/sarojaerabelli/py-fhe#tests), you can verify that worked by running `%run tests/test_polynomial.py` in another cell in the notebook and see the tests run fine. [The documentation also points out examples](https://github.com/sarojaerabelli/py-fhe#examples), I was able to run one in my notebook by executing in a cell `%run examples/bfv_mult_example.py`.

---

If you need a place that will work to test without touching your own system or to compare, you can go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and press 'launch binder' to get a temporary Jupyter session on a remote computer. When that spins up, open a new notebook. In the notebook run the following two lines in the notebook to complete the first four steps covered above:

```bash
!curl -OL https://github.com/sarojaerabelli/py-fhe/archive/refs/heads/master.zip
!unzip master
```

Then continue with step five.

Comment: OK. my current working directory is definately 'C:\Users\myname\...\py-fhe-master'. I checked it with
import os
os.getcwd().

Comment: after tweaking with the paths, it works.  thank you v much!

Comment: It's probably helpful if you mention what needed adjusting. The idea is that it will help people traveling in your footsteps. I cannot tell if your comment really clears it up. One way to think about it is to imagine your current machine dies three months  and you are reading your own post to try and repeat the process 10 months from now.